# The "Transition" object is not working properly

Tags: anylogic

I have a state diagram, and it assumes that agents move from one state to another with an intensity of 41 transitions per hour, but I have only 22 transitions.  Can you explain why this is happening?
[State diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9AO6.png)

I tried to duplicate the diagram and connect it to the end of the diagram, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rate follows an exponential distribution of interarrival occurences in which the rate is 41, so you won't get exactly 41

Now why you get 22? because by default you are using a fixed random seed, so you get the same "random" result.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make it 41, what to use for this?

Comment: make a transition triggered by message, and have an cyclic event that triggers that transition